# want to add JWT filter for only specified url patterns (admin service urls) not for all urls in spring boot security

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

we have all endpoint urls starts with "/api/**" but we want to use jwtFilterRequest for only below urls and all other urls should give permitall.

`GET /api/users`
`POST /api/users`
`GET /api/users/{userId}`

```
httpSecurity.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
.and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
.and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
.and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Kindly help?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: You should create separate configuration for those urls where you can have only one filter i.e. JWTAuthenticationFilter

Comment: Please check out this link : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity

Comment: Edited my request, please help ?